# Formatting html table with alternate row coloring to display json data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have pulled out the jSON data that i need to display in a table but i am having some trouble formatting the table with column headers and appropriate spacing between the columns.

This is my current code for filling a table in html:

Html Page:

```
<body>
    <table id="lessons">

    </table>
</body>
```

and this is what i have for the js function:

```
function populateTable(lesson) {
    var row = $("<tr />");
    $('#lessons').append(row);
    row.append($("<td>" + lesson.name + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + lesson.credits + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + lesson.startDate + "</td>"));
};
```

This is how my outcome looks like now (but with out the headers - i would like to know how to add them as i am adding content to the table so that i won't have a labeled and empty table.

**Name**        **Credits**        **Start Date**
English              4                 01/01/2013
Math                 5                 01/01/2013

But i would like to add comfortable spacing between columns so that it looks like a table  Also it would be great to add alternating colors for the rows.

I was able to add the following css and it fixed the layout and spacing along with the alternating coloring of the data in the table. 
My only problem now is displaying the column headers upon loading the table. I don't want to hard code them into the html because then they will always show before loading content. Plus i am emptying the table between loads so they will get removed if i hard coded them in the html page.

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify question? What is the trouble?

Comment: Also did you try $.html()?

Comment: What is the **intended** outcome? You might want to elaborate a little more on what you want to achieve.

Comment: what is ur json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your comfortable with relying on pure CSS then CSS3 (most modern browsers) will support this with the following style rule where .tbl-striped is the class of your table. You could also replace this with the id your already using. So:

**HTML**

```
<table class="tbl-striped"> ... </table>
<!-- or using the id you already have -->
<table id="lessons"> ... </table>
```

**CSS**

```
/* This CSS will not work in IE8 or lower */
.tbl-striped tr:nth-child(2n-1) td { 
    background-color: #f2f2f2; 
}
/* or using the id you already have */
#lessons tr:nth-child(2n-1) td { 
    background-color: #f2f2f2; 
}
```

Now if you want to do this with just Javascript without changing your code you'll just need to add a global variable and apply the style something like this. PS: This is pseudocode not working as is.

**Javascript**

```
counter = 0;

function populateTable(lesson) {
    if(counter>0){
        ...reset counter to 0
    } else {
        ...add a class to the tr in the following line that will change its color
         var row = $("<tr class="..." />");
         counter++;
    }
    $('#lessons').append(row);
    row.append($("<td>" + lesson.name + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + lesson.credits + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + lesson.startDate + "</td>"));
};
```

This should get you on the right track. You keep editing the answer so I will wait to see if I need to add more to my answer. If you already have all the date ready to go you should just put a loop in the function and run through the way list applying the style to every other row. This will avoid the need of having a global variable.

**Also Something To Consider**

Your JavaScript should really be something like the following to avoid the overhead of calling append all the time. It seems your data size is small so it doesn't really matter but just something to watch out for in the future with larger data.  Again this is pseudocode not working as is.

```
function populateTable(lesson) {
    var row = "<tr><td>"+ lesson.name + "</td>" + ... + "</tr>";
    $("#lessons").append(row);
};
```

Its harder to look at I know but better optimized. You could even get rid of the row variable and just put all that right into the append code.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and added what i have done and got to work but the only thing missing is adding column headers to the table when loading with content.

Answer (score 0):

check the following snippet

```js
var lesson = {
  "name": "xyz",
  "credits": "Abc",
  "startDate": "21-01-2902"
};

$(function() {
  populateTable(lesson);
})

function populateTable(lesson) {
  var row = $("<tr ></tr>");
  var td1 = $("<td></td>");
  td1.html(lesson.name);
  var td2 = $("<td></td>");
  td2.html(lesson.credits);
  var td3 = $("<td></td>");
  td3.html(lesson.startDate);
  row.append(td1);
  row.append(td2);
  row.append(td3);
  $("#lessons").find('tbody').append(row);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="lessons" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      
      <th>Credits</th>
      
      <th>StartDate</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps